# Mixing Windows and Anonymous Authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-authentication, windows-server-2012

Im developing .Net 4.5 Web intranet project. My problem is there is some users can directly login with Windows authentication but also there is some users which they need to login the system with anonymous authentication due to the their company policy there is no posibility that they can add system configuration as trusted network or forest. Therefore system should check windows auth and if it fails without showing the windows prompt screen, should check the anonumys auth and users should login via form (LDAP) but due to the ecosystem of IIS it check anonymous authentication. I tried some solution but they didn't work on Microsoft Server 2012 R2. Is there any way that i can make this happen?

In Conclusion, I need to find a way to check IIS Windows auth after that anonymous Authentication. I found some solutions but they don't work on Microsoft Server 2012 R2. Also tried to get Windows Credentials such as Domain\username. I got it when there is only Windows Auth but when there is Windows and Anonymous authentications are enabled or only Anonuymous authentication is enabled, i couldn't get it because of anonymous authentication. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do one after another. However, you can have one login page, and let both type of users enter username and password. Then you authenticate with AD first, and if fail, authenticate with other authentication method.

Comment: There are at least a few articles on how to achieve mixed authentication (Windows and Forms), and Windows Server 2012 R2 is not different.

Comment: @Win thanks for your suggestion but let all the users login via form is not what i wanted to do.

Comment: @LexLi Yeah almost i check them all but so far without success. Some of users tell that this method or this one working on Microsoft  Server 2008 not working on Server 2012, thats why i mentioned this detail.